# Не ясно, что происходит с данными при выполнении кода.

Tags: c, c++

Вот часть кода.
Не ясно, что делается в циклах. Не понятен даже сам синтаксис.

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t dst;
    uint8_t regnum;
    uint8_t len;
    uint8_t *data;
    uint8_t checksum;
} __attribute__((__packed__)) pkt_t;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pkt.checksum += ((uint8_t *)&pkt)[i];
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        pkt.checksum += ((uint8_t *)data)[i];
```

Answer (score 7):

В первом цикле полю checksum структуры присваивается значение суммы значений первых трех байтов, составляющих структуру pkt. Во втором цикле к этому значению указанного поля прибавляется сумма значений len байтов массива переменных uint8_t, на который указывает поле data.

Comment: Добавлю только, что суммируются числа без знака размером 1 байт (0-255)

Comment: Именно. Говоря в терминах инструкций процессора, производится беззнаковое сложение.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ)

Comment: @mikillskegg разъяснять, так разъяснять. Первые три байта pkt -- это dst, regnum, len.

Comment: @alexiz, я думаю, автор вопроса с этим сам разберется.

Comment: Согласен, @mikisegg